# how to make relations link when editing taxonomy not show

Tags: taxonomy-terms

When a user edits a taxonomy term, there is a link for "Relations" at the bottom.  how can I make that link not show up for certain roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this answer on drupal.org

Yes, you can do it by hook_form_alter()

i.e.
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter()
*
* Some code taken from https://www.drupal.org/node/2158985
*/
function hide_taxonomy_fieldset_form_alter(&$form, $form_state){
if($form['#form_id'] ==='taxonomy_form_term')
$form['relations']['#access'] = FALSE;
}

Answer (score 0):

You may create your custom permission in the hook_permission and then hide this part of the form in using hook_form_alter if user shouldn't have access to this element.

Comment: but where exactly does this link for "Relations" come from .  If we aren't going to be using it - no taxonomy relations necessary , cant we turn it off globally?

Comment: It is a function of the taxonomy module and there are no settings to disable it